# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.hide()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

Hi i have made a simple food ordering app , but When I start it , it crashes and the error thrown in Logcat is this.Please Help Me out...

> ```
>  05-18 17:26:41.104 18166-18166/com.example.sample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>  Process: com.example.sample, PID: 18166
>
>  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity > 
>
> ComponentInfo{com.example.sample/com.example.sample.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: > 
>
> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.hide()' on a null object
>
> reference
>
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2487)
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2547)
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151)
>    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398)
>    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603)
>    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
>    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void > > > 
>
>
> androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.hide()' on a null object reference
>      at com.example.sample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
>      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6355)
>      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2440)
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2547) 
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398) 
>    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603) 
>    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
>    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
> ```
>
> Entire code - [Github](https://github.com/harshsingh1805/Order-App).

Hope You Have All Required Files , ask me if not there. Please Help!!!!

Comment: Always mention Your error module that where you are getting null pointer exception

Answer (score 1):

In your `MainActivity` you use  `getSupportActionBar().hide();` but in your `style.xml` showing you set no actionbar.

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Either Add toolbar in your activity or add `DarkActionBar` instead of `NoActionBar`